# How to finish Activity from AsyncTask class in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, activity-finish

I have an activity with a hamburger menu. When I click on the hamburger menu logout enty, it will call an `AsyncTask`. After the API was called, if the statuscode indicates success then I need to call loginactivity. Up to here it works fine, but my problem is when I press the back button in login then it goes back to the previous screen. How to fix this? How do I finish activity in AsyncTask?

```
public class LandingActivityNew extends AppCompatActivity {
   mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            switch (id){
                case R.id.navItemSettings:
                    Intent iSettings = new Intent(LandingActivityNew.this,SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(iSettings);
                    finish();
                    break;
                case R.id.navItemTC:
                   // Toast.makeText(LandingActivityNew.this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent iTerms = new Intent(LandingActivityNew.this,TermsConditions.class);
                    startActivity(iTerms);
                    break;
                case R.id.navItemPrivacy:
                    //Toast.makeText(LandingActivityNew.this, "Privacy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent iPrivacy = new Intent(LandingActivityNew.this,ConsentActivity.class);
                    startActivity(iPrivacy);
                    break;
                case R.id.navItemReportProblem:
                    Toast.makeText(LandingActivityNew.this, "Report a Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.navItemFAQ:
                    Toast.makeText(LandingActivityNew.this, "FAQ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.navItemShare:
                    Toast.makeText(LandingActivityNew.this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.navItemLogout:
                    new LogoutAsyncTask(LandingActivityNew.this).execute();
                    break;

            }
            return false;
        }

    });

}
```

AsyncTask class like this...

```
public class LogoutAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
   Context context;  
   public LogoutAsyncTask(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    }
   @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {}
   @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    int appStatusCode = getLogoutResponse.getAppStatusCode();
    if (appStatusCode == Constants.APP_STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS) {
        ***Intent logout=new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(logout);
        ((Activity)context).finish();***
    } else {
        ExceptionMessages.showAlertDialog(context, "Unable to Logout", getLogoutResponse.getMessages().get(0), true);
    }
}
 }
```

in onPost() I need to finish the activity call, how to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by "finish activity call"? Do you want to finish activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way,

```
Intent iobj = new Intent(Activity_First.this, Activity_Second.class);
iobj.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(iobj);
```

Comment: Nice and Clean Solution!

Comment: But that Logout asynctask used in many screens...then how can i apply particular class name onPost()???

Answer (score 1):

> How to finish Activity from AsyncTask class in android?

Because passing `LandingActivityNew.this` in `LogoutAsyncTask` class. Do it as:

```
((LandingActivityNew)context).finish();
```

in `onPostExecute` method

Comment: here logoutAsyncTask is a individual class... this asynctask called from many activities

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent logout=new Intent(yourActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        yourActivity.this.startActivity(logout);
        yourActivity.this.finish();
```

Hope it works. Thanx. If this not work tell me i give u better answer

Comment: i am calling AsyncTask not an Activity... n i want to finish activity inside onPost()

Comment: just write  yourActivity.this.finish(); in onPost method of AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Change the LogoutAsyncTask with below code:

```
public class LogoutAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        Activity activity;
        LandingActivityNew obj;

        public LogoutAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            obj = activity.getApplicationContext();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            int appStatusCode = getLogoutResponse.getAppStatusCode();
            if (appStatusCode == Constants.APP_STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS) {
                ***Intent logout=new Intent(activity,LoginActivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(logout);
                obj.finish();
            } else {
                ExceptionMessages.showAlertDialog(activity, "Unable to Logout", getLogoutResponse.getMessages().get(0), true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i called this Asynctask from landingActivitynew this is ok... But i called this LogoutAsyncTask from different classes... then how can i create particular class object in AsyncTask???

Comment: yes i tried... it will work only for landingActivityNew... but it is not working for other classes...

Comment: thank u boss... this is working good for particular activity to Asynctask.